# Magento 2: from php plugin to js knockout in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I have created a plugin on `Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result` that should check on some conditions in the cart's contents.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result">
        <plugin name="om_shipping_filter" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Result"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

This works fine.

Additionally I have created a js mixin that should act on the checkout page.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': 'Namespace_Module/template/shipping'
        }
    },
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'Namespace_Module/js/mixin/shipping': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

shipping.js:

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko'
    ], function ($, ko) {
        'use strict';

        return function (target) {
            return target.extend({
                customError: function () {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

This is also working fine.

I can call `customError` from my custom knockout template:

```
<div role="alert" class="shipping-error message error" translate="'Your cart contains items we cannot ship to your desired country.'" if="customError()"></div>
```

So depending on wether customError returns true or false the message will be shown or hidden.

So the only remaining issue is... how do I get the information from my plugin to the js mixin to properly react? I am totally missing the php to js bridge here.

Thank you

Comment: From Js you want return error code or error it self?

Comment: I want my code from my php plugin to be accessible/usable in the js mixin. Basically: the error message should show or hide depending on my findings in the plugin.